# Explanation of 四方八方

Tags: meaning

The definition of this seems to be "in all directions," but I was wondering "why" this was the case.  I'm guessing 四方 has to do with the four cardinal directions, but I'm not sure what 八方 represents.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It simply [includes the four intermediate directions](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/177871/meaning/m0u/%E5%85%AB%E6%96%B9/) too as a kind of emphasis.